# Powershell Use Parameterized Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server. Without Parameters, this works fine

```
$adw_command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.facts (factID, factName, factKey, factDiv) VALUES ('$factID', '$factName', '$factKey', '$factDiv')"
 $adw_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I try to use Parameters like this, it does not work

```
$adw_command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.facts (factID, factnName, factKey, factDiv) VALUES (@factID, @factName, @factKey, @factDiv)"

$adw_command.Prepare()

$adw_command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@factID', $factID)
$adw_command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@factName', $factName)
$adw_command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@factKey', $factKey)
$adw_command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@factDiv', $factDiv)
$adw_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I must be missing something obvious

Comment: I think you still need put the parameter with single quotes `'` .... `VALUES ('@factID', '@factName' ...`

Comment: Why are calling Prepare *before* adding the parameters?

Comment: You don't need single quotes around the parameters in the insert command.